If I wanted to mess around with how compute units function on a validator node, how would I do it?
Let's say I have a testnet validator and I want to modify how it approaches compute units with the goal of gaining some insight in how compute unit requesting can be optimized. How would you go about this?

Could you be a bit more specific with what you mean by "messing around" exactly?

By this I mean, if I wanted to do some benchmark testing and record it. More specifically, increasing CU constants on different transaction types and then recording performance. Is this possible? If you have any ideas on how I would accomplish this, I'd appreciate it!

It's a bit hard to tell what you're asking, but here are some pointers that might help:
If you want to benchmark your program's CU usage, you can try some new tools like https://github.com/buffalojoec/mollusk.
If you want to tweak the compute unit limits, like max CUs, cost of various syscalls, etc, you can modify the ComputeBudget https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/150f4d7103fb4d9d8bffde0bef2201fbb4ce7bf7/compute-budget/src/compute_budget.rs#L22
Specifically, you can change the values returned during new to anything that you want at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/150f4d7103fb4d9d8bffde0bef2201fbb4ce7bf7/compute-budget/src/compute_budget.rs#L146
You'll just need to build the test-validator yourself by going into https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/validator and running cargo build --release --bin solana-test-validator
